# How can I fix this discord sound Bot error?

Tags: python, discord, bots, args

Hey I started coding lately, now i want to do a Discord bot who can join a Voice Chanel. When i execute this:

```py
BOT_PREFIX = '%'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)

@bot.commmands(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
async def join (ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voicechannel = await channel.connect()
```

after this Error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\DEV\Python\Einführung\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/DEV/Python/pythonProject1/venv/Discord Bot/Bot.py", line 23, in on_message
    @bot.commmands(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'commmands'
```

Answer (score 0):

Its `@bot.command()` not `@bot.commands`. Commands cannot be used in the case here.

Also Can Do
`channel = ctx.author.voice.channel` Rather than `ctx.message.author.voice.channel`
and Passing a variable for  `await channel.connect()` is not needed .

Comment: I did The changes but still dont work. now this error shows up.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/DEV/Python/pythonProject1/venv/Discord Bot/Bot.py", line 10, in <module>
    class myclient(discord.Client):
  File "C:/DEV/Python/pythonProject1/venv/Discord Bot/Bot.py", line 25, in myclient
    @bot.commmand(pass_context=True, aliases=['j', 'joi'])
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'commmand'`